# OpenStreetMap. I can't find some objects in XML, which were on the map

Tags: xml, parsing, openstreetmap

I want to get some node (for example, schools, kindergartens) from Planet.osm (http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Planet.osm), the snapshot of the OpenStreetMap database.
I can see such objects on the map http://www.openstreetmap.org/?lat=59.87326&lon=30.3124&zoom=17&layers=M (school #509, kindergarten #108 and kindergarten #390). But I can't find them in the XML file! I got all objects (s), which have Latitude > 59.86 and Latitude < 59.88 and Longitude > 30.31 and Longitude < 30.32 (this part of map). I've got 42 objects, but I couldn't find school #509, kindergarten #108 and kindergartens #390 and so on. Why?

Are the information on the map and in the XML file quite different? Why I can't find map's object in the XML file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer - http://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/2505/i-see-some-nodes-on-the-map-but-i-cant-find-them-in-planetosm-why

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are using an old planet.osm? Using the openstreetmap api [directly](http://api.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6/map?bbox=30.31,59.86,30.32,59.88) the nodes you search for appear as they should.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know about this feature. It use the last Planet.osm. So, the XML file really didn't contain these objects.